# Is it possible to query Wikidata to get a list of things by item index?

Tags: wikidata

Say, for example, that I wanted to know what the first 100 items are on WikiData (which I do,) without searching in WikiData Q1, Q2, Q3 and so on. Is there a way to write a SPARQL query to find all WikiData entries (either items or properties) associated with a certain numeric index, between 1 and 100? As far as I can tell it seems like SPARQL doesn't have for loops, so I'm not sure if there's a mechanism to generate this data.

Comment: `VALUES ?item {wd:Q1 wd:Q2 … wd:Q100}`?

Comment: That doesn't execute as a SPARQL query.

Comment: For properties: https://w.wiki/bsd

Comment: For small Q-ids: https://w.wiki/bsh